# How to serve static files in Wakanda v2

Tags: wakanda

I've been using Wakanda v2 server for a few months now. I'm using Angular (v2+ not angularJS) for the front end.

I finally got to the point where I want to publish my Angular app through Wakanda. (I suppose I could just as easily use Apache but Wakanda has a web server so why not use it?)

The problem is I don't know how to publish the app with Wakanda. I tried putting the 'dist' files in the web folder but Wakanda keeps saying "Service Not Available".

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Chris, I believe the correct step to deploy is to put the dis 'folder' in the web folder instead of dist 'files'. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is under hard work and schedule for the `v2.2` release.
In the meantime, you can do these steps manually:

- Open the `web` folder in terminal. Right click on `web` folder, then select `open in terminal`
- Run `npm run build`. A `dist` folder is created
- Move the `dist` folder into the `backend` project
- In studio, set the `dist` folder in the `backend` project as the `WebFolder`. Right click on it, then select `set as active webfolder`.

You can have issue with the angular URL strategy. The `#` angular is not understood by Wakanda Server. Therefor, you can add `useHash: true` in the `/src/app/app.module.ts`.

`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`

Source: https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/137

Comment: Thanks – that explains a lot. Looking forward to v2.2 release.