# Wakanda not serving files when using SSL

Tags: angular, wakanda

Wakanda 2.4 with Angular frontend. The project works correctly when accessed over HTTP (port 4201). When I access via HTTPS (443), Wakanda uses the certificates (I can see the certificate with my domain name in the browser) but gives me a 404 page as shown, with no mention of the reason of the error in the browser console or in the server logs (ignoring the favicon.ico error. that file does exist in my `backend/dist` folder).

I tried to resolve this by creating a production build and setting the `backend/dist` folder as my Active Web Folder (as was suggested on a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071913/how-to-serve-static-files-in-wakanda-v2/45322487) i came across), but it still gives the 404 error.

I am not sure why Wakanda is not serving the files and wondering what directory it is looking in for an index page, if that is what it is trying to do.[image]

Comment: As we know Wakanda is a fierce isolationist country, I'm not surprised they're not serving up files.

Comment: Ha ha. when trying to look for documentation for the Wakanda software i always have to include a -panther argument in my google search. derp.

also adding -angularjs argument because searching for angular stuff brings up a lot of angularjs results :/

Comment: Did you change the backend settings to accept HTTPS connections. and place the certificate files in "/Certificates" folder?

Comment: yes @XiangLiu both of those. Wakanda is using the certificate files for certain. I can view the certificate in the web browser and it shows my actual domain name.

Comment: @XiangLiu i've updated my screenshot to show that Wakanda is using the certificates. I have reproduced the bug in a test solution.

Comment: Will you be able to share your test solution with me? I believe you have my email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the test solution @NAMS provided, the certificates are properly installed and recognized.

There are two problems in the solution:

1. Wakanda by default has static file serving disabled and returns 404 to static file requests. It needs to be activated by enabling "**webApp**" Service in server settings.
   [image]
2. While`backend/dist` is set as active web folder, URLs like https://domainname such as https://localhost requires a valid index.html file in the web folder. Otherwise it will also return 404 error.

---

update: @NAMS confirmed turning on "webAPP" and adding index.html solve the issue.