# Reloading page on Angular-Wakanda webserver gives 404

Tags: angular, wakanda

I'm guessing that when you reload the page, the Wakanda server is looking for an absolute path to a file in the web root. So if I reload the page `https://my-site.com/home/products`, there isn't an actual file at that location since I've used the Angular router to virtually create that path.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071913/how-to-serve-static-files-in-wakanda-v2/45322487):

In short, in `app.module.ts`, make sure your router is set up to use the hash in its pathing: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`